# Programmatically sending money (from a business) via Paypal with just a users email address

Tags: api, paypal

We're trying to setup an incentive program in our work place, we want to setup a self service incentive program where each user gets "points" for completing various tasks and then after a certain threshold be able to convert them points into money. But we just want to use email addresses/phone numbers as the method to pay them. Just like the inbuilt [Paypal send money](https://www.paypal.com/au/webapps/mpp/send-money-online) feature.

Is this possible to do via one of their APIs? I've looked through their API's and I can only see receiving money, not sending money....

I would have liked to use Square Cash but that is not available in my country (we're not strictly tied to PayPal if there is an alternative service that will accomplish the goal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a US Business PayPal account you can use MassPay to send payments from your account by specifying the email address.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/mass-pay/

The other option is to use Adaptive Payments to send Implicit Payments from your account to another user. You can specify email address, and if you want to pay the fees for the transaction you can specify that in the call.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/